# How to test a method calls an inherited method?

Tags: php, tdd

Considering the classes below:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function foo()
    {

    }
}

class SubClass extends MyClass
{
    public function bar()
    {
        $this->foo();
    }
}
```

How can I test with [Mockery](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) the fact that the `bar()` method calls the `foo()` method?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend you even try, since this would only lead to testing your implementation rather than the behavior of your implementation.  You should start by determining what it is that you want to do (e.g. "When the customer asks for a bar, it should return a bar"), then how you are going to verify that you returned a bar, then what API you want to be able to invoke to return a bar.  The end result should look something like: actualBar.ShouldNotBeNull() or expectedBar.ShouldEqual(actualBar), rather than some expression of "SubClass.bar should call super class MyClass.foo()".

Comment: In the practical case where I have this problem, `foo()` is a method that checks a value given by users. I have a separate tests for `foo()` but I want to make sure `bar()` is calling it to check the parameter.

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to test for is that some value is validated when calling SubClass.bar().  You shouldn't care if that happens via inheritance, composition, or even code duplication.  By testing for the business case you expect rather than the implementation, you'll be free to refactor without having to change your tests.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should not be using a mocking framework in this case.

Mock frameworks are used to slot in test doubles for all objects that the test subject interacts with. i.e. they are used to isolate the test subject.

Your example is a test of implementation.. which are usually brittle.

Write a test to verify the public outcome of bar - not that it does its job by calling foo on itself. Look for the observable change in the world that would occur if bar does its job. That way if you refactor bar() tomorrow to do the same job via some other implementation, your tests won't break.

Comment: I could have done that but the `foo()` method is gonna be used several times in different `bar()` methods and I didn't want to test outcomes of the `bar()` methods every time. That looked too much like duplication to me.

Comment: So I actually used Dependency Injection instead of inheritance (cf. my answer).

Comment: @SimonJodet - like you inherit classes in prod code, you can have base test fixtures too which contain tests. You can then subclass and override a single virtual method GetObjectToTest(). This way you can run/reuse your tests. Also called contract tests. In NUnit, you can use the Generic/parameterized TestFixtures features to eliminate the subclasses too. Check your unit testing framework if it supports parameterizing test fixtures, if you not you can always fallback to fixture inheritance

Answer (score 0):

My English is rather poor, I may not quite understand what you mean, but:

```
class MyClass
{
    public function foo()
    {
        echo "this is foo";
    }
}

class SubClass extends MyClass
{
    public function bar()
    {
        $this->foo();
    }
}

$test = new subClass();
$test->bar();

$class = new ReflectionClass('SubClass');
Reflection::export( $class );
```

Comment: I'm not sure I get the point in your answer. I don't see any use of Mockery or the way to check that `foo()` has been called.

Answer (score 0):

I actually took another road. I moved the `foo()` method to a new class, tested this class and pass it to the `SubClass` class through dependency injection. That way, I was able to mock the new class and check the `foo()` method was called correctly:

```php
class NewClass
{
    public function foo()
    {

    }
}

class SubClass
{
    public $NewClass;

    public function __construct(NewClass $NewClass)
    {
        $this->NewClass = $NewClass;
    }

    public function bar()
    {
        $this->NewClass->foo();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you've managed to solve your problem, but for reference, this is kind of possible with the latest mockery code.

When creating a mock via the `mock` method, an indexed array is taken as constructor args, so mockery actually extends your class with it's magic and creates an instance.

`ShouldDeferMissing` tells mockery to let it's parent class (`SubClass`) handle calls to any methods Mockery hasn't been told to mock.

This is still a little experimental and I've just realised it doesn't work if you try to pass in quick expectations, but I'll try and put a fix in for that.

```
use Mockery as m;

class MyClass
{
    public function foo()
    {
        return 'foo';
    }
}

class SubClass extends MyClass
{
    public function bar()
    {
        return $this->foo();
    }
}

$subClass = new SubClass;
echo $subClass->bar() . PHP_EOL; // foo


$mock = m::mock("SubClass", array())->shouldDeferMissing();
echo $mock->bar() . PHP_EOL; // foo

$mock->shouldReceive("foo")->andReturn("bar");
echo $mock->bar() . PHP_EOL; // bar
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a few days ago how to do it with the latest version of Mockery as Dave Marshall also hinted at (but in a bit different way).

Let's assume I have a Database class with methods to list tables, drop a table and get a database schema and I want to create "reset" method that uses those 3 methods.
This is how I mocked it with Mockery.

```
<?php
class Database
{
    public function getSchema($version = null)
    {
        //...
    }

    public function listTables()
    {
        //...

    }

    public function dropTable($table)
    {
        //...
    }

    public function reset($version = null)
    {
        $tables = $this->listTables();
        foreach ($tables as $table)
        {
            $this->dropTable($table);
        }

        $schema = $this->getSchema($version);
        foreach ($schema as $query)
        {
            $this->conn->query($query);
        }

    }
}
```

So to test the `reset` method above, here's how I mocked `getSchema`, `listTables` and `dropTable`:

```
class DatabaseTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    //...

    public function test_reset_list_existing_tables_deletes_them_then_create_a_new_schema()
    {
        $app = new \Silex\Application();

        $ConnectionMock = \Mockery::mock('\Doctrine\DBAL\Connection');
        $ConnectionMock
            ->shouldReceive('query')
            ->with('SQL query 1')
            ->once()
            ->ordered('reset');
        $ConnectionMock
            ->shouldReceive('query')
            ->with('SQL query 2')
            ->once()
            ->ordered('reset');
        $app['db'] = $ConnectionMock;

        $Database = \Mockery::mock('\Database[listTables,dropTable, getSchema]', array($app));
        $Database
            ->shouldReceive('listTables')
            ->once()
            ->ordered('reset')
            ->andReturn(array('system', 'users'));
        $Database
            ->shouldReceive('dropTable')
            ->with('system')
            ->once()
            ->ordered('reset');
        $Database
            ->shouldReceive('dropTable')
            ->with('users')
            ->once()
            ->ordered('reset');
        $Database
            ->shouldReceive('getSchema')
            ->with(1)
            ->once()
            ->ordered('reset')
            ->andReturn(array('SQL query 1', 'SQL query 2'));

        $Database->reset(1);
    }
}
```

Specifically, look at how I create the mock:

```
$Database = \Mockery::mock('\Database[listTables,dropTable, getSchema]', array($app));
```

I list the method I want to mock in "[]" and I pass the `Database` constructor as an array in the second parameter of `mock`.

`reset` that I want to test is not mocked so it's the actual implementation that is executed when I do `$Database->reset(1);`.